# When was the term "Einstein–Rosen bridge" first used in a Sci-Fi work?

Tags: history-of, wormhole

While we see [wormholes in fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormholes_in_fiction) all the time, they aren't always addressed as *Einstein–Rosen bridge*. At this time, there are two examples in my mind which used exact term *Einstein–Rosen bridge*:

- In *Thor: Ragnarok* (2017) movie, Banner addressed *Devil's Anus* as *Einstein–Rosen bridge*.
- In an episode of *Justice League* (2001) or *Justice League Unlimited* (2004) TV series, Flash ran at lightspeed on Green Lantern's track to create a wormhole near Sun to suck something out of Sun. Here, Batman or someone in Justice League used the term *Einstein–Rosen bridge*.

When was the term *Einstein–Rosen bridge* first used in Science Fiction?

Comment: Refined lower bound is [1935](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.48.73) when Einstein and Rosen first wrote about these bridges in Physics Review. A paper titled "*The Particle Problem in the General Theory of Relativity*"

Comment: @Edlothiad just beat me to the punch

Comment: I appreciate you thought of *Ragnarok* because it just came out, but the Bifrost was also named as an E-R Bridge in *Thor* (2011).

Comment: @Edlothiad Do you know when the term *Einstein–Rosen bridge* was first coined? Probably, Einstein and Rosen didn't use that term in their 1935 paper, and it was coined later by somebody else.

Comment: @user14111 it was not used in that paper but they coined the term “bridge” in that paper. The only things I could find for Einstein-Rosen Bridge were around the 90s which is far too late. I would assume the first paper to cite their paper would’ve named it the Einstein-Rosen Bridge

Comment: Depending on how you define 'sci-fi works', Blue Öyster Cult's song from 1981, _Heavy Metal: The Black And Silver_ has a lyric, "We forged the Einstein bridge tonight".

Comment: @LAK It's not *Einstein-Rosen Bridge*.. Rosen word is missing..

Comment: @Discovery But that is what they're referring to - it's pretty clear from the context of the song, which is a bunch of imagery related to astronomy and astrophysics. Adding the '-Rosen' just wouldn't fit the timing.

Comment: @LAK Most of wormholes refer to Einstein-Rosen Bridge, but I am asking different thing. Also, from the song's lyrics, they can refer to fictional bridges which have not been theorized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1979**:  *The Black Hole*.  If memory serves me right, there is a scene were scientists Dr. Hans Reinhardt and Dr. Alex Durant whisper about the possibility of an Einstein-Rosen bridge connected to the black hole.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just searched the transcript: https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=black-hole-the (there's a line `There might be an Einstein-Rosen
bridge to consider.`)

Answer (score 7):

**1983:** ["The Last Einstein–Rosen Bridge"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95740) is the title of a science fiction short story by [Rudy Rucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudy_Rucker) which was first published in his 1983 collection [*The 57th Franz Kafka*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?34936).

The term *Einstein–Rosen bridge* does not occur in the body of the story.

Answer (score 5):

Earliest example that pops in my head (I am sure there are earlier) is [Sliders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliders?wprov=sfti1), an SF tv series from 1995-2000. They distinctly talk about crossing the Einstein-Rosen Bridge in the first episode, although it's rarely referred to as such afterward.

Edit: I stand corrected, they talk about an ERP bridge, so not exactly what the question was asking.

Comment: I believe they actually called it the "Einstein-Rosen-Podolsky Bridge" Podolsky to emphasize the cross-universal travel (whereas an ER bridge can be two points in the same universe).

Comment: @starpilotsix That just sounds like a mistake, actually.  The Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen paradox has nothing to do with the Einstein-Rosen bridge, but the EPR name is more famous.

Comment: I think you are both correct, FWIW.